# how to fix this Visual Studio code path error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

when ever I run some code I get this error even though the path exists
[image]

**PS D:>  d:; cd 'd:\IIT\Degree\Software Development I [Programming]\CourseWork\Course_Work'; & 'C:\Users\himas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\himas.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '10124' '--' 'd:\IIT\Degree\Software Development I [Programming]\CourseWork\Course_Work\Q1_001.py'
cd : Cannot find path 'd:\IIT\Degree\Software Development I [Programming]\CourseWork\Course_Work' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:6

- d:; cd 'd:\IIT\Degree\Software Development I [Programming]\CourseWor ...
- ```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (d:\IIT\Degree\S...ork\Course_Work:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

pydev debugger: critical: unable to get real case for file. Details:
filename: D:
drive: D:
parts: ['']
(please create a ticket in the tracker to address this).
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\himas.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 221, in _get_path_with_real_case
return _resolve_listing(drive, iter(parts))
File "c:\Users\himas.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 192, in _resolve_listing
raise FileNotFoundError('Unable to find: %s in %s' % (
FileNotFoundError: Unable to find:  in D:\

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\himas.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 226, in _get_path_with_real_case
return _resolve_listing(drive, iter(parts))
File "c:\Users\himas.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 192, in _resolve_listing
raise FileNotFoundError('Unable to find: %s in %s' % (
FileNotFoundError: Unable to find:  in D:**

Comment: try in a directory without spaces and `[]`

Comment: Post error as text, not as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question